# How to execute a 3 GB sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, restore

i have a 3GB sql file and i can't open directly on management studio,so,i have to split the file and execute the parts.but,how i'll split the file? or execute directly without outOfMemory exception?

i'm using SQL SERVER 2014 and i didn't have sucess restoring the .sql with cmd..

Comment: this may be better suited for dba.

Comment: Does it contain "GO" lines?  If so, just loop through it, accumulating a batch in memory, then executing when you get a GO command.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this before..Use sqlcmd utility.. very easy to use.. in this case you just have to give the path of one big script file with few other parameters. Refer to microsoft documentation.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

that sucks. you should be able to load the .sql file via command line. this is how most data warehousing companies load large db/sql files in order launch databases. this should NOT be opened with any IDEs and loading it via command line is the only way it's done.

if I were you I'd try to load the file via cmd again because that's the way to do it.